# Slick JS adding space on left side when using infinite, center mode slideshow

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I am trying to use Slick JS to make a slider where slides are looping infinitely, but visible at the same time. I have created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/xblack/pen/bGeeyMJ) to show the demo. If you interact with the demo, you will find as soon as you come back to the slide 1, slides on the left of the slide 1 disappear except 5,6 ...

Can anyone help me fix this?

```js
    $(".customslider-1").slick({ 
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed:300,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding:'0',
      variableWidth: true, 
      arrows: false,
      focusOnSelect: true,
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've often seen weirdness when `centerMode` is used without setting `slidesToShow`. Setting `slidesToShow: 5` resolves this problem for me in your CodePen.

```js
$(".customslider-1").slick({ 
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed:300,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: 0,
  variableWidth: true, 
  arrows: false,
  focusOnSelect: true,
});
```

Comment: .First of all thanks for the reply. Yes I know I can resolve that by setting Slide number or by removing centerMode. But I need the slide to be in center and want the slides to fit the widths.